# Seems google 翻译 pronouncing in wrong way

Tags: pronunciation, tones

好久不见。

> 下午 我 会 去 超市。
>
> Xiàwǔ wǒ huì qù chāoshì.

The problem is that the last pinyin which should be pronounced like "shu" in English but Google-translate(android app) actually pronounce it as like "she"

Should I quit using Google translate app for training my pronounciation skill?

Or still the pronounciation of Google translate app can be understood by native speakers of Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

The vowel in shì in Standard Mandarin is pronounced as a close back unrounded vowel [ɯ]. Meanwhile the "oe" in "shoe" is a close back rounded vowel [u] and the "e" in "she" is a close front unrounded vowel [i].

The vowel in shì is most close to the sound "oo" in "goose" with a strong Californian accent. (The RP pronunciation of "oo" is [ʉ], a close central rounded vowel. )

Comment: In IPA the Japanese "u", or う, is sometimes classified as an [ɯ] sound, but not close enough to the [ɯ] in shi4 in Mandarin as it features a unique rounding style.